# Why is requestAnimation frame called multiple times for some frames, and not at all for others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, redux, requestanimationframe

I have a redux app which uses `requestAnimationFrame` to render a new state on every TICK, however Google Chrome seems to be calling `requestAnimationFrame` up to 3 times(!!) for some ticks, and not at all for others, leading to janky animations.

In React development mode:
[image: Chrome performance timeline screenshot 1]
In React `NODE_ENV=production` mode:
[image: Chrome performance timeline screenshot 2]

It's rendering at 60fps already, so multiple unnecessary `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks per 16ms frame are highly wasteful of CPU resources.  Frames that don't have a tick also cause laggy-ness in the animations.  My tick function only takes 4ms to compute (well under the 16ms budget), and I only have one callback running on the page.

Here is the animation code that handles dispatching my redux call on every tick.

```
class AnimationHandler {
    constructor(store) {
        this.store = store
        this.animating = false
        store.subscribe(::this.handleStateChange)
    }
    handleStateChange() {
        if (!this.animating) {
            this.tick()
        }
    }
    tick(timestamp) {
        this.animating = true
        this.store.dispatch({
            type: 'TICK',
            current_timestamp: (new Date).getTime(),
            // reducer handles updating rendered state to this point in time
        })
        window.requestAnimationFrame(::this.tick)
    }
}

window.animations = new AnimationHandler(window.store)  // redux store
```

What could be causing Chrome to do this, and how can I make it so that there's one consistent `tick()` call per frame rendered, no more no less?

Comment: having the same problem! did you happen to find an answer?

Comment: It got better when I started using the `NODE_ENV=production` environment variable to compile React in production-mode.  I never found out the root cause unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was a bug on my side and I suspect it always is.

In your code , calling `tick()` schedules an infinite loop of requestAnimationFrame since requestAnimationFrame() is always called as part of tick(). This is normal.

It's not a problem if `tick()` is called only once outside of the loop. It's not happening in your example, but it's likely that you initiated several loops in the real application.

Just in case, I would change your code to:

```
handleStateChange() {
        if (!this.animating) {
            this.animating = true // immediate
            this.tick()
        }
    }
```

In my case, I was reusing the `tick()` method, adding layers of requestAnimationFrame().

Example: (WRONG!)

```
// init
window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)

// on some other events
tick() // WRONG! will create a new layer of requestAnimationFrame loop!
```